# Dismantle a nested unorderd list

Tags: jquery

I have a nested unordered list

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="root">
  <li>item-a</li>
  <li>item-b
    <ul>
      <li>subitem-b1</li>
      <li>subitem-b2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item-c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The Result I want to have, is two seperate lists. Don't mind about the reference between those lists.

Here is the jquery I already have:

```js
var list = $('#root');

function traverseList(list){
    if(list.length > 0){
    list.children('li').each(function(i){
        if($(this).children('ul').length > 0){
        traverseList($(this).children('ul'));
        }else{       
          $('#nav').append($(this).parent());
      }
    });
  }
}

traverseList(list);
```

So I have the recursively function 'traverseList' to iterate through all the 'li' elements looking for a child 'ul'.

If there is none, I take the parent 'ul' and append it to the framing 'div'.
This was just a first step on the way to my solution and I wondered that it's working.

**Result**

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>subitem-b1</li>
    <li>subitem-b2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="root">
    <li>item-a</li>
    <li>item-b</li>
    <li>item-c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Questions**

1. Where is my orignial list?
2. The first 'li' doesn't have an 'ul' so it should take the parent/root 'ul' - including the sub 'ul'?

So I don't understand the result.

[Edit in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dillinja/g27oyksf/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=g27oyksf)

So maybe someone can give me food for thought. Thank you.

Comment: why not just find all child ul and move them into the nav div: https://jsfiddle.net/yd59hqmw/